# Change size of ActionBar Navigation List view

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My `ActionBar` list navigation is broken on phone-size devices. The wording in the navigation is cut off, due to the "?" icon.

[image]

I have already set `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` on the menu item, but it has a higher priority than the list navigation.

I have also tried to modify the view created by the `Adapter` to set the width of the returned `TextView` but this was unsuccessful.

---

**How do I change the size of the navigation list**, so that the items are correctly displayed, and the "?" icon is moved into the overflow?

Comment: Note that list and tab navigation in the action bar is deprecated as of the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in the production Android release that follows.

Comment: have you try `orderInCategory`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I am aware of that. My client is still chasing to catch up with the (pre-Navigation-Drawer) basic ActionBar UI, and changing that at the moment is not an option. If I could, this question would be moot.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847789/android-3-0-changing-order-of-icons-in-the-action-bar

Comment: @shayanpourvatan setting `android:menuCategory` and `android:orderInCategory` does not have an effect on this issue.